# numpy: efficiently summing with index arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have 2 matrices M and N (both have > 1 columns). I also have an index matrix I with 2 columns -- 1 for M and one for N. The indices for N are unique, but the indices for M may appear more than once. The operation I would like to perform is,

```
for i,j in w:
  M[i] += N[j]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this other than a for loop?

Comment: Missing in the question: the obvious `M[w[:, 0]] += N[w[:, 1]]` fails because the indices in `w[:, 0]` are not unique, so values get overwritten.

Comment: So what happens when you do not do an in-place addition but create a third array. Does that give you the desired result?

Comment: If you don't do the operation in place, you end up with a new array of length matching I with `I[i] = M[w[i,0]] + N[w[i,1]]`. How do you then group this matrix by `w[:,0]` and sum its values?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For completeness, in numpy >= 1.8 you can also use `np.add`'s `at` method:

```
In [8]: m, n = np.random.rand(2, 10)

In [9]: m_idx, n_idx = np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 20))

In [10]: m0 = m.copy()

In [11]: np.add.at(m, m_idx, n[n_idx])

In [13]: m0 += np.bincount(m_idx, weights=n[n_idx], minlength=len(m))

In [14]: np.allclose(m, m0)
Out[14]: True

In [15]: %timeit np.add.at(m, m_idx, n[n_idx])
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.49 us per loop

In [16]: %timeit np.bincount(m_idx, weights=n[n_idx], minlength=len(m))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 us per loop
```

Aside of the obvious performance disadvantage, it has a couple of advantages:

1. `np.bincount` converts its weights to double precision floats, `.at` will operate with you array's native type. This makes it the simplest option for dealing e.g. with complex numbers.
2. `np.bincount` only adds weights together, you have an `at` method for all ufuncs, so you can repeatedly `multiply`, or `logical_and`, or whatever you feel like.

But for your use case, `np.bincount` is probably the way to go.

Comment: Your example uses vectors `m` and `n` rather than matrices, so `np.bincount` works in this example but not in my use case.  On the other hand, `np.add.at` does exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using also `m_ind, n_ind = w.T`, just do `M += np.bincount(m_ind, weights=N[n_ind], minlength=len(M))`

Comment: Much more elegant than my solution; I had a hunch `bincount` could solve this but I couldn't figure out the pattern.

Comment: I think this will only work if N is 1D array. `np.bincount` is throwing a ValueError for me if N is a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, let's define

```
>>> m_ind, n_ind = w.T
```

Then the `for` loop

```
for i, j in zip(m_ind, n_ind):
    M[i] += N[j]
```

updates the entries `M[np.unique(m_ind)]`. The values that get written to it are `N[n_ind]`, which must be grouped by `m_ind`. (The fact that there's an `n_ind` in addition to `m_ind` is actually tangential to the question; you could just set `N = N[n_ind]`.) There happens to be a SciPy class that does exactly this: [`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html).

Example data:

```
>>> m_ind, n_ind = array([[0, 0, 1, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1]])
>>> M = np.arange(2, 6)
>>> N = np.logspace(2, 5, 4)
```

The result of the `for` loop is that `M` becomes `[110002 1103 4 5]`. We get the same result with a `csr_matrix` as follows. As I said earlier, `n_ind` isn't relevant, so we get rid of that first.

```
>>> N = N[n_ind]
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> update = csr_matrix((N, m_ind, [0, len(N)])).toarray()
```

The CSR constructor builds a matrix with the required values at the required indices; the third part of its argument is a compressed column index, meaning that the values `N[0:len(N)]` have the indices `m_ind[0:len(N)]`. Duplicates are summed:

```
>>> update
array([[ 110000.,    1100.]])
```

This has shape `(1, len(np.unique(m_ind)))` and can be added in directly:

```
>>> M[np.unique(m_ind)] += update.ravel()
>>> M
array([110002,   1103,      4,      5])
```

Comment: @Veedrac Try again, it actually works. `m_ind, n_ind = w.T; N = N[n_ind]; update = csr_matrix((N, m_ind, [0, len(N)])).toarray(); M[np.unique(m_ind)] += update.ravel()`.

Comment: <strike>*That* gives me `ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,1)` from the `M[np.unique(m_ind)] += update` part.</strike> Just missed the `ravel`, is fine.

Comment: @Veedrac: sorry about that. (It is in the answer, fortunately.)